# PHP Mail Script Stopped Working

Tags: php, arrays, email

My mail script has recently stopped working for no apparent reason (Damn 1&1) and I was hoping someone could help me out... PHP is not my strong point.

Basically people fill in an online form, select the download links they want sending via a checkbox system and they receive an email that provides them with the links and a quick message, also copying in me so that I can see who has downloaded the files and what they've had.

```
<?php
$email = $_POST ["from"]  ;

if ( isset ( $_POST [ 'buttonPressed' ] )){
if ( array_search('', $_POST) ) {
  echo "<p><font color='red'>You must fill in all required fields, please <a href='http://mywebsite.com/downloads/access.php'>try again</a></font></p>"; 
  exit; 
} 

if( empty($_POST['cb']) ) { echo "<p><font color='red'>You must select a download by using the checkboxes on the left, please <a href='http://www.mywebsite.com/Downloads/access.php'>try again</a></font></p>";
  exit; 
 }
else 
{ 
 }

if (preg_match('/@/', $email))
{
}
else
{
  echo "<p><font color='red'>You must enter a valid email, please <a href='http://www.mywebsite.com/Downloads/access.php'>try again</a></font></p>"; 
  exit; 
}

if (preg_match('/\./', $email))
{
}
else
{
  echo "<p><font color='red'>You must enter a valid email, please <a href='http://www.mywebsite.com/Downloads/access.php'>try again</a></font></p>"; 
  exit; 
}

$checkbox = implode( "\r\n" . "\r\n" , $_POST['cb'] ); 


// REPLACE THE LINE BELOW WITH YOUR E-MAIL ADDRESS.
$to = $_POST["from"];
$subject = 'WEBSITE - mywebsite Downloads' ;

// NOT SUGGESTED TO CHANGE THESE VALUES
$message = "Dear" ." ". $_POST ["name"] ."\n". "Thank you for visiting mywebsite.com, we look forward to dealing with " . $_POST ["companyName"]." in future." ."\n"."\n" . "If there is anything further that you need, we would be delighted to arrange one of our technical representatives to call you." . 
"\n"."\n".
"Please find your download link below:"."\n"."\n".     

"$checkbox" .


"\n"."\n". "Please do not reply to this email, all replies in relation to this email should be sent to person@mywebsite.com"
 ;
$headers = 'From: no-reply@mywebsite.com ' . PHP_EOL ;   "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: person1@mywebsite.com, person2@mywebsite.com ' . "\r\n";
mail ( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ;


echo "<p><font color='green'>A download link has been sent to $to</font></p>"; }

else{
?>
```

Side note: I am aware I could use a separate php script to check the validity of the info provided but this has served me ok up until now.

Comment: PHP mail function highly depend on the server provider and its restrictions.

Comment: tell us more about your error logs.

Comment: Use PHPMailer and please protect inputs with 
`function xssafe($data, $encoding = 'UTF-8')
{
    return htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, $encoding);
}`
for example:
`$from = xssafe($_POST ["from"]);`

Comment: This is the error coming up on the site:

Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments in E:\kunden\homepages\2\d524510309\www\mywebsite\Downloads\access.php on line 207